# Thread safety of std::string::c_str()

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, stdstring

It appears to me as if there is a requirement in modern C++ that after calling `operator[]()`, `c_str()`, or `data()`, it is guaranteed that string's contents are terminated by a null.

However, is it possible that this initialization may be done "lazily"?  That is, the buffer allocated for the string's content may not be null terminated until after one of those functions is called, potentially making usage of this function not thread_safe?   I am ideally looking for a specific citation from the standard, one way or the other.

Comment: All `const` qualified member functions are thread safe in the standard library.

Comment: How would you get a pointer to this content without calling `c_str()` first?

Comment: @Mat but one can still call the `const` version and get null-terminated string. So it is nonsensical that non-const `data()` would modify it in some way. The non-const version simply returns a non-const pointer, so user could edit it.